# Booking System SQL Concept

Tags: sql

I am working on a project for a Hotel Booking System.
The database should be able to have multiple hotels with x rooms and x guests. A booking can have x rooms and x guests. So what i came up with is the following diagram:

[image: Simple Data Structure]

My question is what is the best or lets say nicest and proper way to make a query as simple as possible to get all the bookings for a single hotel?

One idea would be to add the hotel id to the booking. But i could also just join the guest or rooms and then access the hotel id.

Not sure which way i should go...happy for any ideas...:-) or is my design bad anyways?

Comment: you do not have direct relationship with hotel and booking in the diagram. because of that you are not going to have simple sql to query the data. Please check this data model http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/hotels/

Comment: thanks for the link...
that is why i was wondering if i shall add that link or not...but i suppose that is the best way to do it

Comment: Otherwise your sql and storeproc is going to very long/complex and poor in the performances.

Comment: yup...that was my main concern...